# Why does my binary search run slower than my linear search in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, runtime, binary-search, linear-search

Here is my code for binary search:

```
function result = binarySearch(a, key)

binaryFound = false;
halfIndex = fix(length(a)/2) + 1;

if a(halfIndex) == key
    binaryFound = true;
elseif length(a)==1 && a(1)~=key
    binaryFound = false;
elseif key > a(halfIndex)
     newHalfArray = a(halfIndex+1:end);
     binaryFound = binarySearch(newHalfArray, key);
else
    newHalfArray = a(1:halfIndex-1);
    binaryFound = binarySearch(newHalfArray, key);
end
result = binaryFound;
```

And here is my linear search:

```
function linearFound = linearSearch(a, key)

linearFound = false;
for j=1:length(a)
    if a(j) == key
        linearFound = true;
    end
end
```

In both cases, 'a' is an array of sorted integers and 'key' is the value I'm looking for.
Having run multiple tests with a range of array sizes and averaging of runtimes, I consistently find my linear search to be faster than my binary search. I know from theory that the binary search is supposed to be faster. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can use the `profile` tool to check where is Matlab spending time, and see if it is a problem of algorithm or your implementation. I guess that, in your case, it has to do with memory handling and creating those 'half' arrays, but profiler can tell you better

Answer (score 4):

Some of the problems:

*1) You use recursion in binary search, so you have more function calls.*

*2) You create new matrix every time you call `binarySearch`*

```
newHalfArray = a(1:halfIndex-1); //or
newHalfArray = a(halfIndex+1:end);
```

Matlab is clever enough not to create the same matrix over and over again but it has some cost.

*3) You have some unnecessary piece of code like `result=binaryFound`.* *This is not even a nanosec but just saying*

Here is a sample code I just wrote, I tested with few example but not thoroughly tested which is quite faster than your BinarySearch

```
function found = binarySearch(a, key)

found = false;

beg = 1;
fin = length(a);
mid = floor(length(a)/2);

while ~found
    if a(mid) == key
        found = true;
    elseif fin-beg == 1
        break
    elseif a(mid) < key
        beg = mid;
        mid = ceil((fin+beg)/2);
    elseif a(mid) > key
        fin = mid;
        mid = floor((fin+beg)/2);
    end
end

end
```

**EDIT: I forgot to tell the most important thing:**

*4) What is the key you are searching for?*

```
        Best case       Avg case      Worst case
LS      1 comparison    n/2 comp.     n comp
BS      1 comparison    O(log_n)      O(log_n)
```

So, if you are searching for the first element in the list, there is no way Binary Search can compete with Linear Search.

Comment: "Matlab is clever enough not to create the same matrix over and over again" -> I'm pretty sure the data is copied there, over and over again. A MATLAB matrix never points to partial data for another matrix. `b=a` doesn't copy data, but `b=a(5:10)` or even `a=a(5:10)` does copy data.